# Symfony2 Form: Tags Collection does not get persisted

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `Upload` Entity , that can have many Tags,

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="uploads")
 */
protected $tags;
```

and a `Tag` can be in Many Uploads

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Upload", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="upload_tag")
 */
protected $uploads;
```

i have a Form, where i can upload a file, and select tags with multi-select....here is a snippet from the `UploadType` file

```
......other form elements.....
$builder->add('tags', 'entity', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'property' => 'name',
    'class' => 'BoiMembersBundle:Tag',
));
```

The forum submits fine, without errors.....but when i look into my upload_tag, which represents the ManyToMany relationship in my mysql DB, i see no new lines!!!

So the application does not report any errors what so ever..other form elements of Upload get insterted fine, and forwards to the "success"-Route, but i do not see persistanse for the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Upload` it's not the owner of the relation with `Tag` and you're persisting `Upload` with new entities (of `Tag` type) inside the relation itself. In fact, it has the `mappedBy` attribute.

You can configure the cascade `option`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="uploads", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tags;
```

Or make `Upload` the owner of the relation (if you think you'll never persist `Tag` entity with a new `Upload` inside it):

```
class Upload
{
    /**
     * BIDIRECTIONAL - OWNING SIDE
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="uploads")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="upload_tag")
     */
     protected $tags;
}    

class Tag
{

    /**
     * BIDIRECTIONAL - INVERSE SIDE
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Upload", mappedBy="uploads")
     */
     protected $uploads;
}
```

See [Working with Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) on Doctrine 2.x documentation.